# Python Regular Expressoin For Finding SQL Statement and convert it into Redshift Expression

Tags: python, mysql, regex

I have written a python script which detect a particular SQL query with fixed select and multiple AND clauses using python re module. Here is the regular expression which I have written for this Query .

Here is the SQL Query stored in the python variable

```
code=""" IF EXISTS
    (
    SELECT 1
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE Table_Name = 'Cycle_YYYYMM_BankBB'
    AND Table_Catalog = 'XXNORMDBNAMEXX'
    AND Table_Schema = 'dbo'
    AND Table_Type = 'BASE TABLE'
    )

    DROP TABLE XXNORMDBNAMEXX.dbo.Cycle_YYYYMM_BankBB
    GO"""
```

And this is the regular expression which I have written for such SQL Query

IF EXISTS\n(\nSELECT 1\nFROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES\n.*DROP TABLE (.*)\nGO

Whenever I get such type of query in python script using regular expression its should replace this with BYE and it should get the table name

```
WHERE Table_Name = **'Cycle_YYYYMM_BankBB'**
```

Here is the SQL query for replacing this

```
re.sub(r'IF EXISTS\n\(\nSELECT 1\nFROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES\n','bye', code, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

After replacing the query with bye it should also get the table name from the above query

When I am trying to run it sometime regular expression is not detecting the statement . Please help with the regular expression for above particular statement.

Answer (score 0):

There may be numerous reasons why, but one is probably spaces:

```
re.sub(r'IF EXISTS\n\(\nSELECT 1\nFROM
```

Your SQL has spaces following a `\n`

```
....SELECT 1
....FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
....WHERE Table_Name = 'Cycle_YYYYMM_BankBB'
```

You could select them with `\s*`, like so

```
re.sub(r'IF EXISTS\n\s*\(\n\s*SELECT 1\n\s*FROM
```

Comment: can you tell me that the regular expression which i have written is correct or not  ??

Comment: Yes, its correct. You can test regexes for example here: https://regex101.com Just paste the Regex above and your text below. If you add the `\s*` as I suggested above, it matches part of your SQL, as expected.

Comment: I am not getting the solution exactly as i want

Comment: Probably `\s` includes `\n`, so you could toss the latter?  (You would probably need to change `\s*` to `\s+`.)